# Display recyclerView list of checks using information scanned from QR code

Tags: java, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-asynctask, dao

I hope this question is much improved on my last, apologies, still trying to get the hang of this. I am working on a project for work where a user scans a QR code, this is then displayed in a subsequent activity. What I wish to do is search the database for the checks that match the information from the QR code.

The QR code reader works fine and the position information it retrieves is passed and displayed in the next activity. I have passed the three arguments of int positionNumber, int weekNumber and String weekday through an AsyncTask following an answer provided on here using a static class. There seem to be no code errors, but the required list is not being retrieved. I have been working on this problem all week and tried online tutorials, videos and textbooks. Really thought the multiple parameters on AsyncTask would have done this for me but no luck.

I have attatched the code for the activity, Viewmodel, repository, dao and database. Please could someone guide me, really want to get this functionality working in the app.

```
@Dao
public interface InspectionInformationDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM inspection_information WHERE pos_number =:positionNum AND week_number =:weekNum AND week_day =:dayOfWeek ")
    List<InspectionInformation> getDailyChecks(int positionNum, int weekNum, String dayOfWeek);

    @Insert
    void insert(InspectionInformation inspectionInformation);

}

REPOSITORY CODE

   private MutableLiveData<List<InspectionInformation>> checkSearchResults = new MutableLiveData<>();




    public PosCheckRepository(Application application) {
        PlantPosCheckDatabase plantPosCheckDatabase = PlantPosCheckDatabase.getInstance(application);

        posInfoDao = plantPosCheckDatabase.posInfoDao();
        inspectionInformationDao = plantPosCheckDatabase.inspectionInformationDao();

        allPositionInfo = posInfoDao.getAllPositionInfo();

    }

    public MutableLiveData<List<InspectionInformation>> getCheckSearchResults() {
        return checkSearchResults;
    }

    private void asyncFinished(List<InspectionInformation> results) {
        checkSearchResults.setValue(results);
    }

  private static class SearchParams {
        int positionNumber;
        int weekNumber;
        String weekDay;

        SearchParams(int positionNumber, int weekNumber, String weekDay) {
            this.positionNumber = positionNumber;
            this.weekDay = weekDay;
            this.weekNumber = weekNumber;
        }


    }

private static class QueryAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<SearchParams, Void, List<InspectionInformation>> {
        private InspectionInformationDao asyncTaskDao;
        private PosCheckRepository delegate = null;

        QueryAsyncTask(InspectionInformationDao dao){
            asyncTaskDao = dao;
        }
        @Override
        protected List<InspectionInformation> doInBackground(final SearchParams... params) {
            int positionNumber = params[0].positionNumber;
            int weekNumber = params[0].weekNumber;
            String weekDay = params[0].weekDay;
            return asyncTaskDao.getDailyChecks(positionNumber,weekNumber,weekDay);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<InspectionInformation> result) {
            delegate.asyncFinished(result);
        }
    }

public void findChecks(int positionNumber, int weekNumber, String weekDay) {
        SearchParams searchParams = new SearchParams(positionNumber, weekNumber,weekDay);
        QueryAsyncTask task = new QueryAsyncTask(inspectionInformationDao);
        task.delegate = this;
        task.execute(searchParams);
    }


    VIEWMODEL CODE

      private MutableLiveData<List<InspectionInformation>> checkSearchResults;



    public PosCheckViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        repository = new PosCheckRepository(application);
        checkSearchResults = repository.getCheckSearchResults();
    }

    MutableLiveData<List<InspectionInformation>> getCheckSearchResults() {
        return checkSearchResults;
    }

    public void findChecks(int positionNumber, int weekNumber, String weekDay) {
        repository.findChecks(positionNumber, weekNumber, weekDay);
    }


MAIN ACTIVITY CODE

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.inspection_check_activity);


        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        dateTime =  findViewById(R.id.insp_date);
        locationDetails = findViewById(R.id.inspected_location);
        positionNumber =  findViewById(R.id.poition_number_inspected);
        calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        final PosCheckAdapter adapter = new PosCheckAdapter();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        posCheckViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(PosCheckViewModel.class);


        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras == null) {
            return;
        }
        setDateTime();
        setDayOfWeek();
        setLocationDetails();
        setPositionNumber();
        setWeekNumber();
        posCheckViewModel.getCheckSearchResults().observe(this, new Observer<List<InspectionInformation>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<InspectionInformation> inspectionInformations) {
                adapter.setInspectionInformations(inspectionInformations);
            }
        });

    }
```